# Call to Azure hangs on socket read

Tags: java, azure, sdk

I'm making calls to Azure using their Java SDK.  Occasionally, the calls hang on a socket read and never return.  I've tried using version 0.5.0 and 0.6.0 of the SDK with the same results.  Is there a way to set the read and connect timeouts?  I've tried using the following, but they don't seem to be used.  Any suggestions?

```
    URI uri = new URI("https://management.core.windows.net"); //$NON-NLS-1$
    configuration = ManagementConfiguration.configure(uri, subscriptionId, keyStoreLocation, keyStorePassword, KeyStoreType.jks);
    configuration.setProperty(Configuration.PROPERTY_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, new Integer(1));
    configuration.setProperty(Configuration.PROPERTY_READ_TIMEOUT, new Integer(1));
    computeManagementClient = ComputeManagementService.create(configuration);
```

Comment: Have the very same problem when using 0.7.0 version. Were you manage to figure out what the issue is or how to set the timeout?